# Unexpected error in C inline function

Tags: c, inline

I am trying to write a function returning the maximum value between two integers. The below code gives an error message when I run it on repl.it. But when I remove "inline", it becomes normal. Why am I doing wrong? Thanks!

```
#include <stdio.h>

inline int max(int a, int b){
  return (a>b)? a: b;
}

int main( ) {
  int a = 3, b = 4;
  int c = max(a,b);
  printf("%d", c);
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: What error message exactly?

Comment: /tmp/ccK89pCB.o: In function `main':
main.c:(.text+0x21): undefined reference to `max'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status

exit status 1

Comment: Oh, yes. You may be right. It works well on another online compiler. Thanks!

Comment: It's ok on repl.it, but with C++, not C

Comment: @manuell - C++ and C treat `inline` differently.